# Ember.js Component properties data set by Ajax JSON

Tags: json, ajax, ember.js

I have a Component that has an injected service, which makes an Ajax call. I can receive the JSON data successfully and can dump it into the console after the promise "THEN" returns.

Here's my component. I can see the dumped data, but how do I set the component properties with that JSON and have it accessible in the template?  Also, why can't I use "this.get" in my function below?

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    attr_types:  Ember.inject.service('svc-attrtypes'),
    atype_list: [],
    actions: {
        getATypes: function() {
            this.get('attr_types').getTypes().then(function(json){
                console.log(json);
                this.atype_list = json;
                console.log(this.atype_list);
                // below returns: TypeError: this.get is not a function
                this.get('atype_list').pushObjects(json); 
            });
        }
    }               

});
```

In my template I have this:

```
{{#each atype_list.alltypes as |a|}}
    <li>{{a.attr_type}} - {{a.attr_type_desc}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

If I manually place my JSON into the atype_list it shows perfectly on the template.  But if I try to set it after my Ajax returns, nothing shows, except for in the console output.

I appreciate any help. I am sure I a missing something simple. ( or more likely, I'm just going about this all wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`This` changed with anonymous function passed to `then`. You have to save `this` or use es6 arrow function syntax.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    attrTypes: service('svc-attrtypes'),
    atypeList: [],
    actions: {
        // es6 version
        getATypes(){
            this.get('attrTypes').getTypes().then(array => {
                this.set('atypeList', array); //replaces original array
                this.get('atypeList').pushObjects(array); // adds array's elements to the end
            });
        }
        // es5 version
        getATypes: function () {
            var _this = this;
            this.get('attrTypes').getTypes().then(function(array){
                _this.set('atypeList', array);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

*You wrote that you are new to ember, so I added little more syntax sugar. Also check [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) if you don't know about that already.*

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe I didn't think of the _this=this thing!  I was more hung up thinking there must be an Ember hook somehow.  Thanks so much for the extra "sugar" too! Yes, ES6 is very new as well, and much of what I read is confusing.  Adding that to my learning list. Thank you!